# Android-Avoid file download more than one time from Firebase

Tags: android, file, firebase, firebase-storage

I have a chat app which let's user send image,video's etc via Firebase and when other user start syncing with Firebase database, it first download file into local storage like other app (Whatapp, Messenger) and then play from there.

But my issue is whenever user activity refreshed all files download again and again and make duplicate copies of same files. How can I avoid this condition.

Here my AsyncTask where I am downloading file from Firebase storage.

```
public class DownloadAttachment extends AsyncTask<Void, String, String> {
    String DownloadUrl,fileName;
    File file;
    Context context;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    public static final String TAG="###Download Attachment";

    public DownloadAttachment(Context context, String downloadUrl, String fileName) {
        DownloadUrl = downloadUrl;
        this.fileName = fileName; //UUID.randomUUID().toString()
        this.context=context;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        int count;
        try {
            File root = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

            Log.d(TAG,"DO IN BACKGROUND RUNNING");
            File dir = new File(root.getAbsolutePath() + "/Downloaded Files/");
            if (dir.exists() == false) {
                dir.mkdirs();
            }


            URL url = new URL(DownloadUrl); //you can write here any link
            file = new File(dir, fileName);

            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Log.d(TAG, "download begining");
            Log.d(TAG, "download url:" + url);
            Log.d(TAG, "downloaded file name:" + fileName);

       /* Open a connection to that URL. */
            URLConnection ucon = url.openConnection();

            //this will be useful so that you can show a typical 0-100% progress bar
            int lengthOfFile=ucon.getContentLength();
       /*
        * Define InputStreams to read from the URLConnection.
        */
            InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);

       /*
        * Read bytes to the Buffer until there is nothing more to read(-1).
        */
            ByteArrayOutputStream baf = new ByteArrayOutputStream(5000);
            int current = 0;
            long total=0;
            while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) {
                baf.write((byte) current);
                total=total+current;
                //PUBLISH THE PROGRESS
                //AFTER THIS onProgressUpdate will be called
                publishProgress(""+(int)(total*100)/lengthOfFile);
            }


       /* Convert the Bytes read to a String. */
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            fos.write(baf.toByteArray());
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
            Log.d("DownloadManager", "download ready in " + ((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) / 1000) + " sec");
            Log.d(TAG,"File Path "+file);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("DownloadManager", "Error: " + e);
        }

        return file.toString();
    }    

}
```

I can't check name of the file cuz i am generating random name of file with UUID.

Please guide me with this issue

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion you can maintain a table for downloaded files, in local sqlite database, containing two columns:

- TAG: filename or some unique id of the file
- URI: uri/path of the
  file where it was stored on device.

Before downloading any file you should check whether its entry exists in the table using TAG column. If it does then don't download it from firebase rather fetch it from the device using URI. If not, then you can download the file and insert a row for this file in the table.

Comment: You might be right but its possible that we should wait for some more solutions before accepting this as answer